# Removing the top margin on a page

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to remove this bit of space at the top of my page, I've tried a number of things and read around. The only thing that seems to work is *{margin:0}, but I don't really want to do that. Anyone have some insight on what the problem is here?

You can view the page in question here: http://www.ryanlaurence.com/new/

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div id = "Banner">
        <p>Banner</p>
    </div>
    <div id = "Nav">
        <div id="stripe"></div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href = "#"> Link</a>  -  </li>
            <li><a href = "#"> Link</a>  -  </li>
            <li><a href = "#"> Link</a>  -  </li>
            <li><a href = "#"> Link</a>     </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="Content">
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div id="Footer">

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
body, html{
    background-color: #404040;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#Banner{
    background-color: #333333;
    height:200px;
    top:0px;
}
#stripe{
    height: 10px;
    top: -14px;
    position:relative;
    background-color: #262626
}

#Nav{
    width:100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #262626;
}
#Nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    color: gray;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
#Nav ul li{
    display: inline;
}
#Nav ul a{
    color: gray;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: "Orator Std", verdana;
    text-align: center;
}
#Nav ul li a:hover{
    color: white;
}

.Content{
    background-color: #333333;
    /*height: 800px;*/
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
}
.Content div{
    height:800px;
}
#Footer{
    background-color:#57B4CC;
    height:150px;
}
```

Comment: If you want have only the top margin to be zero. You can explicitly mention that like margin-top:0px;

Comment: @kjana83 The problem is that I can't remove it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the CSS:

```
#Banner p {margin:0}
```

The paragraph in your banner div has a default margin that you want to get rid of.

Answer (score 0):

Some elements and browsers has some default styles that you need to overwrite to meet your needs.

I suggest you to use [CSS reset](http://www.cssreset.com/) script by `Eric Meyer`.

This is not only fix your problem but also help you to prevent and save a lot of time from dealing with cross browser compatibility problems in the future.

```
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video {
    border:0;
    font-size:100%;
    font:inherit;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section {
    display:block
}
body {
    line-height:1
}
ol,ul {
    list-style:none
}
blockquote,q {
    quotes:none
}
blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after {
    content:none
}
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing: 0
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b2F8K/)**

Answer (score 0):

I tried to give margin-top: -7px. It worked. But not sure why its has some space over there.